# QPainter Cache Possible?

Tags: qt, caching, qpainter

I've Pie Shaped widgets that needs extensive paintings. So I want to cache the QPainter Once it have been painted in paintEvent. and reuse it latter. Is there any direct or hacky way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a QPixmap as a cache, QPainter can use it to paint onto directly as well.

Comment: So I need to set the size of the QPixmap same as the size of Widget ?

Comment: Yes.  QPixmap is QPaintDevice derived, so think of it as a canvas.